# I get an error when uploading to my server

Tags: php, file-upload

It worked on a localhost fine. However when I uploaded to my server I get this error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/55a92822cc379^0C3C66D7264AB79F9D6963823CCC90CEC2A8221.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/chrispantelli.me/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 51`
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpk7R86o' to 'uploads/55a92822cc379^0C3C66D7264AB79F9D6963823CCC90CEC2A8221.png' in /var/www/chrispantelli.me/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 51`

This is the code:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=9w9hy2Lj

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors. It's not your code, it your file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

That means the user ID that owns the php (web service) process doesn't have write permissions on the destination folder. The script doesn't list what that destination folder is, so check to make sure that the web service owner has write permissions there (or you can also use a group, if another user ID owns the directory.)

Edit:
770 => user (owner) has read/write/execute, group is read/write/execute, and other users have no permissions.
For example, if the http process running on your host was owned by the "apache" userID, then if the uploads directory was owned by "apache" as well, then 700 permissions would work. The user who owns the directory can write to it.
If the uploads directory was owned by root, lets say, but the group was "apache", then assuming the apache user was in the apache group, 770 permissions would work, because you're giving the group write permissions as well.

In order to find the user that owns your http process, assuming you are running apache:

```
ps -ef |grep http
```

This should give you something that looks like this:

```
apache 1234 5678 0 Jul17 ?   10:00:24 httpd
```

In this case, the 1st column is the user that owns the process. You can get the groups of that user with:

```
groups apache
apache : apache
```

This means that the user id "apache" is a member of the group "apache". So if that's the case, then try changing the owner of the uploads directory like this:

```
chown apache /path/to/your/uploads/dir
```

Then you can change the permissions to 700 (because apache is the only ID that needs write access if people are uploading from your web site.

```
chmod 700 /path/to/your/uploads/dir
```

Likewise, if another user id (lets say root) owns the upload directory, and you want to keep it that way, you can do this:

```
chgrp apache /path/to/your/uploads/dir
chmod 770 /path/to/your/uploads/dir
```

This will give the members of the apache group (which is likely just the one user "apache") write access to that directory, allowing your uploads.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: So could this be Chmod 770 permissions?